# mysql list in one column result of another select

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have a very huge table where I need to find duplicate rows. In order to find them I run:

```
SELECT firstcolumn, count(*) AS c FROM invoice GROUP BY firstcolumn HAVING c > 1 ORDER BY c DESC
```

This works as expected: I get a table with firstcolumn in one column and the  total number of rows that holds firstcolumn's duplicate value.

Now, I need to add a new column to this result table: a new column "ids" which lists all the ids of the rows that have the same firstcolumn's value. So for instance, if my original table has 3 rows with the same  firstcolumn value (eg. "somerandomstring") and this 3 rows have 11,32,356 as ids, I should end up with a result table like this:

```
"somerandomstring",3,"11,32,356"
```

So, how can I modify my  query so that I  can have the list of ids in my third column ?

I tried modifying my query as such:

```
SELECT firstcolumn, count(*) AS c, (SELECT secondid FROM invoice AS so WHERE so.firstcolumn = si.firstcolumn) AS secondcolumn
FROM invoice AS si
WHERE firstcolumn != "" 
GROUP BY firstcolumn HAVING c > 1 ORDER BY c DESC
```

but it doesn't work. No error  appear and the query just keeps loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) to the rescue:

```
SELECT firstcolumn, 
       count(*) AS c, 
       group_concat(secondid) as ids
FROM invoice AS si
WHERE firstcolumn != "" 
GROUP BY firstcolumn 
HAVING c > 1 
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: thank you, you're a life saver it works!!! Marked your solution as accepted. I tried to upvote it as useful but it says  i don't have enough reputation sorry